Standard Form of Mathieu's Equation
I am currently taking a nonlinear dynamics class and we are currently learning Floquet theory. We covered the Mathieu equation, and the Hills-Mathieu equation.
I am currently analyzing the stability of the inverted pendulum close to $\theta = 0$, and the governing equation I have is
$$mL^2 \ddot{\theta} - mL \ddot{y}\sin\theta - mgL\sin\theta = 0$$
where y(t) is the parametric excitation, $y(t) = A \cos(\omega t)$.
My question is do I have to convert the equation to standard form for the Mathieu equation? If so, why is this conversion necessary given the slight differences between the equations? Could you also explain how to convert my equation to the standard form shown below?
$\ddot{x} + (\delta + 2\epsilon \cos(2t)) x = 0$
where $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ are constants.

I talked to my professor about it and the reason we want to keep it in this form is because the solution we went through in the notes depends on this form. Anything different would likely affect the outcome, so for simplicity we ensure that the ODE in the given problem is in the "standard form" for the sake of keeping in line with the notes.
